# Get frames from a shared library (.SO) with STABS

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, binutils, readelf

I have an Android SO library with STABS debug info, as opposed to DWARF. I'd like to get the call frame information from it, similar to what `...-readelf --debug-dump=frames-interp` outputs.

With most NDK built libraries, `readelf` does the trick, but not with this one.

Is frame info even supported in STABS? If so, what kind of executable file parser can get it out?

`Addr2line` has no trouble with that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what kind of executable file parser can get it out?

`objdump -G` should do the trick.

Comment: That was a complete STABS dump. Now, do you know where in STABS might the frame structure info be?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Unlie DWARF, STABS format is not structured -- it's a big lump of everything together. I don't believe STABS is actually flexible enough to describe non-standard frame layouts, but I haven't looked at STABS for the last 12 years, so don't quote me on that.